Union of subclasses in TypeScript
This is a weird one... 
Scenario:
Say I have a base class with two or more classes:
// Base class
class Something <T> {
    constructor (x: T) {
        // ...
    }
    doSomething (value: T) {
        // ...
    }
}

// Subclasses
class AnotherThing extends Something<string> {}
class YetAnotherThing extends Something<number> {}

// Union of subclasses
type SomethingUnion = AnotherThing | YetAnotherThing;

Now say that there is an object type which has values of type SomethingUnion...
type SomethingMap = {
    [key: string]: SomethingUnion;
}

...and a mapped type that extracts the type parameter from each member of a given SomethingMap (here DataOf):
// A type that extracts `T` from `Something<T>`.
type GetT<S extends Something<any>> = S extends Something<infer U> ? U : never

// A mapped type that extracts the type parameter from every `Something` subclass.
type DataOf<T extends SomethingMap> = {
    [K in keyof T]: GetT<T[K]>;
}

Issue:
If I have some value someMap (this could be anything of the type SomethingMap), and another value someOtherMap, which is a DataOf type created from someMap, and I want to map over someMap's entries, TypeScript infers the type of thing.doSomething(...)'s parameter to be of type never, when I would instead like the type to instead be the same as the type of valueToDoThingsWith:

// Note: someMap declared previously with type `SomethingMap`
// Note: someOtherMap declared previously with type equivalent to `DataOf<typeof someMap>`

const entries = Object.entries(someMap); // [string, SomethingUnion][]


const mappedEntries = entries.map(([key, thing]) => {
    const valueToDoThingsWith = someOtherMap[key] // string | number

    // value has the type `SomethingUnion`, and the parameter `value` is `never`, which
    // does not work with `valueToDoThingsWith`, which holds the intended type "string | number".
    thing.doSomething(valueToDoThingsWith)

    // ...
})

Is there a way to work around such a issue, and to have doSomething take a parameter of the same type as valueToDoThingsWith?

"If I have some value someMap of type SomethingMap, and another value someOtherMap, which is a DataOf type created from someMap" Can you [edit] your code to be a [mre] that shows this instead of just talking about it? Or are we allowed to define these however we like to answer the question?

(see prev comment) I'd say this needs to be generic in a way the compiler can follow, and it has little to do with unions or subclasses. The approach I'd take looks like this playground link. Note that you need a type assertion to convince the compiler that Object.entries(someMap) produces an array of the right type where key and thing are related to each other. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

@jcalz [first comment] in my specific case, the data is loaded from an API request, so anything that satisfies SomethingMap in this case should be fine. I will edit the question to make this clearer. Thank you very much for your time.

@jcalz [second comment] Yes, the code fully addresses the question. Thanks again!

But someOtherMap is... also loaded from the API? How do you plan to convince the compiler that someMap and someOtherMap are of related types to each other? I suppose it's out of scope for the question as asked and when I write my answer I'll just assume you end up with a pair of values related in just the right way.

I'd say you should write a generic helper function which accepts a someOtherMap of some object type T, and a someMap of the mapped type {[K in keyof T]: Something<T[K]>}, meaning that the compiler should understand that for any key key of type K, the value of someOtherMap[key] should be a suitable input for the someMap[key].doSomething() method:
function process<T extends object>(
    someMap: { [K in keyof T]: Something<T[K]> },
    someOtherMap: T
) {

    const entries = Object.entries(someMap) as // <-- asserting
        { [K in keyof T]: [K, Something<T[K]>] }[keyof T][];

    const mappedEntries = entries.map(
        <K extends keyof T>([key, thing]: [K, Something<T[K]>]) => {
            const valueToDoThingsWith = someOtherMap[key]
            thing.doSomething(valueToDoThingsWith)
        })
}

That compiles as desired. Note that I need to do a type assertion to convince the compiler that Object.entries() produces an array of key-value pairs such that the value is of the type corresponding to the key. The default typings in TypeScript just produce [string, unknown], which isn't strong enough. See Preserve Type when using Object.entries.
Anyway, once you do that, you need the entries.map() callback to also be generic, so the compiler again matches key with thing. Once you do that, thing[key] is seen to be of generic type Something<T[K]>, whose doSomething() method accepts a T[K], which is the type of valueToDoThingsWith, since someOtherMap is of type T and key is of type K.
Note that this works without ever mentioning SomethingUnion or string/number It's fully generic and only cares about Something.

Let's just make sure we can call process():
const map = { a: new AnotherThing("abc"), b: new YetAnotherThing(123) };
const otherMap = { a: "def", b: 456 }
process(map, otherMap); // okay

Looks good. Note that it will only work if TypeScript agrees that map and someOtherMap are related properly. And that might be tough if map comes from an API call. But this is out of scope for the question as asked.
Playground link to code

Here are two potential solutions:
Option 1:
Solution:
Use GetT<...> to generate a union of the types of T in each Something<T> subclass, rather than using a union of the subclasses themselves.
// This will create a union of `GetT<...>` results for each constituent of SomethingUnion
type TypesOfT = GetT<SomethingUnion>;

Then, use this TypesOfT type as the type argument to Something<...>:
type BetterSomethingUnion = Something<TypesOfT>;

Why this works:
Consider the map call:

// Note: `someMap` and `someOtherMap` have the types discussed above.

const entries = Object.entries(someMap); // [string, SomethingUnion][]


const mappedEntries = entries.map(([key, thing]) => {
    const valueToDoThingsWith = someOtherMap[key] // string | number

    // `thing` is of type `SomethingUnion`
    thing.doSomething(valueToDoThingsWith) // error

    // ...
})

In the callback function, thing has the type SomethingUnion, which is the same as:
type SomethingUnion = AnotherThing | YetAnotherThing;
type SomethingUnion = Something<string> | Something<number>;

However, to generate the desired result, a type along the lines of Something<string | number> is needed, since the argument to .doSomething(...) would then be typed string | number, which is the desired behaviour.
TypeScript cannot assign Something<string> | Something<number> to Something<string | number>, since they are not the same in some cases. This means that the argument to thing.doSomething(...) evaluates to never.
Using the type BetterSomethingUnion, as described in the solution, will generate the following:
type TypesOfT = GetT<SomethingUnion>; // string | number
type BetterSomethingUnion = Something<TypesOfT>; // Something<string | number> !!!

Which is exactly what is needed.
So, a type such as the following could be used to replace SomethingMap:
type BetterSomethingMap = {
    [key: string]: BetterSomethingUnion;
};

Option 2 (not recommended)
Solution
Simply cast valueToDoThingsWith to never (this must be repeated with every call to .doSomething(...), however, and my likely cause more issues later on):
// Regular TypeScript (`.ts`) file only:
thing.doSomething(<never>valueToDoThingsWith);

// OR

// Regular TypeScript (`*.ts`) files, and TypeScript JSX (`*.tsx`) files:
thing.doSomething(valueToDoThingsWith as never);

Why this works:
Casting valueToDoThingsWith to never means that TypeScript will consider valueToDoThingsWith to be assignable to the argument of thing.doSomething(...), which expects never as the parameter type, so that typechecking errors occur.
Why this is not recommended:
Although casting to never solves the issue described in the question, it may not cover other issues which may rise from using SomethingMap rather than BetterSomethingMap (or an equivalent type), and can cause issues when maintaining the code as well, since the root cause of the error has not been properly addressed.
